# ValueError: cannot use inplace with CategoricalIndex

Tags: python, pandas, addition, categorical-data, in-place

I am using **pandas 0.18**.

This fails

```
 cat_fields[f[0]].add_categories(s,inplace=True)
```

However the [docs](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.Series.cat.add_categories.html#pandas.Series.cat.add_categories) say

> inplace : boolean (default: False)
>
> Whether or not to add the categories inplace or return a copy of this categorical with added categories.

Am I missing something ?

I am creating a superset of categories/columns across many dataframes to eventually be able to concatenate them.

My error:

> ValueError: cannot use inplace with CategoricalIndex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need assign to original column, because [`Series.add_categories`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cat.add_categories.html) has `inplace` parameter and it works nice.

But in [`CategoricalIndex.add_categories`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.CategoricalIndex.add_categories.html) has also `inplace` parameter, but it fails. I think it is bug.

```
cat_fields[f[0]] = cat_fields[f[0]].add_categories(s)
```

or:

```
cat_fields[f[0]] = cat_fields[f[0]].cat.add_categories(s)
```

Sample:

```
cat_fields = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3]}, index=['a','d','f'])


cat_fields.index = pd.CategoricalIndex(cat_fields.index)
cat_fields.A = pd.Categorical(cat_fields.A)
print (cat_fields)
   A
a  1
d  2
f  3

s = ['b','c']

cat_fields.A.cat.add_categories(s,inplace=True)

print (cat_fields.A)
Name: A, dtype: category
Categories (5, object): [1, 2, 3, b, c]


cat_fields.index.add_categories(s,inplace=True)
print (cat_fields)
```

> ValueError: cannot use inplace with CategoricalIndex

Comment: Yes I realized that. I am just wondering if this is a bug or my bad ?

Comment: Give me asec, i test it.

Comment: What return `f[0]`?

Comment: and what `cat_fields[f[0]]` ?

Comment: f[0] is a field name. I have a list of tuples with field name-dtype.    In the example above, there is a dictionary with a **Categorical Index** per f[0] field. I am building up the the index, collecting all unique categories to eventually reassign categories to all fields in all dataframes and do a pd.concat.

Comment: Hmmm, so my answer was helpful? Or not?

Comment: Yes jezrael, it confirms my thinking it is a bug. Forgive I am too new to the netiquete of Stackoverflow. If I should give you credit for your response let me know how. It is not a solution as there isn't any, hence I did not clicked on solved.

Comment: Ya, you and me get credit if you click to empty `nike` sign under `0` near top left of my answer. Thank you.